# proof multiplying combinations - algebra struggles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I don't have to write a proof I just have to show that $(^{n}_{k})(^k_m)=(^n_m)(^{n-m}_{k-m})$
But I am struggling to expand this. 
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}*\frac{k!}{m!(k-m)!}$$

Once I get it to this point I am having no luck multiplying it out to make it look like the other side should look

Comment: yes i'm positive. the problem is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LHS: You're forming a committee of $k$ people that can be chosen out of $n$ people,  $n \choose k$ combinations. Then, from those $k$ people you choose a board of $m$ people, $k \choose m$ combinations. So in total there are ${n \choose k} {k \choose m}$ combinations.

RHS: Reversed order of the LHS, first you choose a board of $m$ persons out of all ($n$) people. Then, from the $n-m$ people left, you choose the committee of $k-m$ persons.

Since they both count the same things, they must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the expansion of $(^{n}_{k})$ and simplify the fractions..

$(^{n}_{k})(^k_m)=(^n_m)(^{n-m}_{k-m})$

$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot \frac{k!}{m!(k-m)!}=\frac{(n-m)!}{(k-m)!(n-k)!}$

$\frac{n!}{m!}=(n-m)!$, which is true.